# python code multirasters zonal statistics

Tags: arcpy, zonal-statistics

```
env.workspace = "C:\Users\\Documents\pythonMODIS\extract"

# Set local variables
inZoneData = "mask.shp"
zoneField = "Classes"
inValueRaster = "mi1511171_clip.tif"
outTable = "zonalstattblout02.dbf"


# Execute ZonalStatisticsAsTable
outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, inValueRaster, 
                                 outTable, "NODATA", "MEAN")
```

I have several modis images and one layer mask for 3 regional field classes. I want to iterate zonal statistics in all rasters data set,  get a summary dbf table but keeping each raster name, mean, min, max by region class.

I had run once for each image but I want to iterate all the images together. I wonder if I need to define a rasterlist in the workspace and to include that in outZsat

I need some help with the code.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the outputs in a list and merge them after the fact.

```
inRasterFolder = r"..."
arcpy.env.workspace = inRasterFolder
tables = []

for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
    outTable = "table_" + str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", "")[0:8] + ".dbf"
    tables.append(outTable)
    outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, raster, outTable, "DATA", "ALL")

arcpy.Merge_management(tables, "finalDbf.dbf")
```

For brevity the usual imports, vars, cleanup etc is not shown. If you need to add custom columns (I am not perfectly clear how you want to handle the different classes in your zoneField) you can add and then calc fields right after the ZonalStatsAsTable command.